# Package name for camera action in HTC,Samsung,Google and Micromax devices

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing an application to block/unblock camera according to user's choice.I am starting camera using Intent.

I have no real device and as my knowledge, in each manufacturer the package name is different.

How can I get the package and class name of camera action for each manufactures?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665045/how-to-get-package-name

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But from that we can get the package name for the current running device. I don't have a real device and i want to know the package names in all the devices.

Answer (score 0):

you can download "package name viewer" from play store free one,*emphasized text* which will show you all the package name which are in your smartphone
[here you can download the apps](https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.gijoon.pkgnameviewer%26hl%3Den&ei=xf2oVK_LLM30aMjkgKgK&usg=AFQjCNEXOQ2yDvNqcIIOehzGNJCuMRfwFg&sig2=AuTNb_KnzVIBI2CWSfJbrw&bvm=bv.82001339,d.d2s)

Comment: I think he asks for a programmable way not an external app, So, this is not the right asnwer