# Open a .apk file from a app

Tags: android, apk

Can anyone tell on how to open multiple apk files from one app .I have made a application for Carousel now while when the user clicks on the icon it should open that particular app's apk file likewise I have 6 items in Carousel .I know it can be done by onItemClickListener all I want to know is how to open a apk file from a app.

Thanks

Comment: Define "open" -- do you want to install the apk?

Comment: Do you mean to launch an application when you click on an item in the carousel?

Comment: I think you have to build first of all file manager. Or simply on app icon you can write the path of that apk so that on click of that icon that app executes.

Answer (score 0):

You should know the Application package name before opening new application,

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.address","com.package.address.MainActivity"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

OR

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Those items you are showing up in the carousel are static? or are you reading them from Intent using some category filter? If it's the last one, you could save the packageName reading the `List<ResolveInfo>` returned when you query your `packageManager`.

Here you can see an example of what I'm talking about: [How to get package name of camera application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665045/how-to-get-package-name-of-camera-application)